# Stolen Package with Ipad Pro WiFi only

Tags: ipad, wifi

I purchased an Ipad Pro 12.3" for my kid for school, and we purchased it directly with Apple. The carrier claims they delivered it and left it in the porch (we dont have a porch). Then their excuse is that Apple didnt request signature delivery so they left it at the door or porch and they cant do anything. I contacted Apple and they are doing due investigation, but I was pretty much told that they cannot block the device even if I ask for it and having the serial number which is in my receipt. Is there anyone that knows how to do this? I can check the info on the order receipt, but since it never reached us, it has no apple ID on it nor anything. It was stolen BRAND NEW on the package, or delivered to the wrong house.

Comment: I'd let the courier / Apple sort it out. File a police report for documentation, and if you don't receive a satisfactory resolution contact your credit card provider for a charge-back on the purchase.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions asking for legal advice are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck in terms of locking it out. If you had ordered it from a business or school registered with Apple Schoo Manager it would have been pre-associated with your organization, but as a regular consumer, with no Apple ID ever having been associated with the device, you have no ability to control or tack it.

However, I suspect that Apple will send you a new one and since you had no personal info on the device I would not invest much time into tracking it or locking it.

Comment: Claims like "I suspect that Apple will send you a new one" should be backed by evidence.